# A sequence of four numbers such that the first three are in G.P. and the last three are in A.P. What is wrong in my solution?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

I came across a question today

> Given a sequence of four numbers such that the first three are in G.P. and the last three are in A.P. with common difference $6$. If the first and the fourth number are equal, then common ratio of the G.P. is?

---

Now correct way of doing this is given as:

Let the last three numbers be $a, a+6, a+12$, so that the first three numbers are $a+12, a, a+6$. As these are in G.P. $$a^2 = (a+12)(a+6) \Rightarrow a=-4$$ 
Common ratio is $-2$

---

But how I did this is

I took first term of G.P. as $a_1$ and the first term of A.P. as $a_2$. So the series is  $$a_1, (a_1r) \text{ or }(a_2), (a_1r^2) \text{ or } (a_2+6), a_2 +12$$

So,  $a_1 = a_2+12$ and $r= \dfrac{a_2+6}{a_2}$ and $a_1r^2 - a_1r=6$

Solving these three equations I get Common ratio (r) = $-0.5$

---

What is wrong in my solution? I know that my solution is bit more time consuming but why is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the four terms be:
$$\begin{align}
&a\\
&ar=&&a-12\\
&ar^2=&&a-6\\
& &&a\end{align}$$
From the above, we have
$$6=a(1-r^2)\\
12=a(1-r)$$
Dividing (allowed as $r\neq 1$) and solving gives
$$r=-\frac12\quad\blacksquare$$

---

Solving gives $a=8$, hence the four numbers are 
$$\lbrace 8,-4,\;2,\;8\rbrace$$

Answer (score 1):

The common ratio **is** indeed $-\frac{1}{2}$. You can check that the answer $a=-4$ of the first solution produces common ratio $-\frac{1}{2}$, and not $-2$.

Answer (score 0):

<>let the last three numbers of the set which are in A.P be b,b+6,b+12 and the first number be a.

→thus ,the four numbers are a,b,b+6,b+12

given,a=b+12-----(1)

also, given a,b,b+6 are in G.P

by equation (1)

→b+12,b,b+6 are in G.P

→b/(b+12)=(b+6)/b

→b²=(b+6)(b+12)

→b²=b²+18b+72

→18b=-72

→b=-4

→a=-4+12=8

hence the four numbers are 8,-4,2,8

I hope this will help u ;)

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typing math.